# How to return directly from last activity to first using mobile back button?

Tags: java, android

Suppose that, I have 5 activities. A, B, C, D, E which contains back and next button. We can go from A to B, B to C, C to D, D to E by pressing the next button. When I am in activity E and I want to come in activity A, then I have to press four times back button of mobile not of my app. How can I come from activity E to A at once by pressing mobile back button?

Comment: So, Is your problem resolved?????

Answer (score 1):

Override the `onBackPressed()` method of activity E as follows:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityE.this, ActivityA.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: this code works fine. It is what I needed, so I didn't tried other code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by the following...
First one, By defining   `android:parentActivityName=""` attribute in activiteis in Manifest file.
 Second one through `onBackPressed()` method.

Answer (score 0):

try this in activity C

```
    Intent startMain = new Intent(context, ActivityA.class);       
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(startMain);
```